# React Router and Material-Table - filter column values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

How can I pass values of Route params into the filter fields of a React table?

I'm using a component called material-table.
Got a set of links like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link to="/Products/Dogs/Foods">Dog Food Products</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="/Services/Cats/Grooming">Cat Grooming Services</Link>
  </li>
</ul>

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/:business/:category/:product" component={Material_Table}/>
</Switch>
```

Then in the Material_Table component, I need to filter the columns based on those url params. Right now just putting them in an h4:

```
<div className="alert">
      <h4>Business: {business}. Category: {category}. Product: {product}.</h4>
    </div>

    <MaterialTable
        title = "Projects"
        icons = {tableIcons}
        columns={[
            {
                title: 'Name',
                field: 'name'
            },
            {
                title: 'Business',
                field: 'values[9]'
            },
            {
                title: 'Category',
                field: 'values[10]'
            },
            {
                title: 'Product',
                field: 'values[8]'
            },
        ]}
        data = {items}
        options ={{
          filtering: true
        }}
        />
```

Tried putting expressions right in the columns object but that does not work.
I know there's an option for default value, but that doesn't seem right either.
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using `defaultFilter` on each column works:

```
<MaterialTable
    title = "Projects"
    icons = {tableIcons}
    columns={[
        {
            title: 'Name',
            field: 'name'
        },
        {
            title: 'Business',
            field: 'values[9]',
            defaultFiler: business
        },
        {
            title: 'Category',
            field: 'values[10]',
            defaultFilter: category
        },
        {
            title: 'Product',
            field: 'values[8]',
            defaultFiler: product
        },
    ]}
    data = {items}
    options ={{
      filtering: true
    }}
    />
```